# Open Source Image Hosting or File Sharing website in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, open-source

I would like to know if there are any free open source or paid software for hosting images (like tinypic.com imageshack.us) or file sharing (4shared.com or rapidshare.com) developed in ASP.NET.

And If I have to develop the same, how do I remove the 2 gb limit on upload in IIS?

This question contains both programming as well as non programming question.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you uploading more than 2GB at a time?  That is asking for failure-related problems.  Even at 100Mb that is multiple minutes of transfer, why not break it into more reasonably sized chunks?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the most obvious answer, [Gallery2](http://gallery.menalto.com/), is written in PHP. It may be that installing PHP under IIS and configuring Gallery2 is significantly less work than writing something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Chevereto looks and its verry awesome i love it, so easy to use and looks great, plus its open source what else can you ask for except that i wish it was a file hosting service too :)

http://chevereto.com/